# Como utilizar o comando REPITA nesse algoritmo?

Tags: portugol

Estou com a seguinte questão mas não consegui entender como fazer usando o comando `REPITA`:

> Escreva um algoritmo que solicite a idade de várias pessoas (UTILIZE O REPITA). Informe o total de pessoas com menos de 25 anos e o total de pessoas com mais de 50 anos. O programa termina quando idade for negativa (Não deve ser utilizada na contagem).

Esse foi um que eu fiz bem parecido, porém usando o comando `PARA...FACA`:

```
var
 menor,idade,maior,contador:inteiro
 idade_media:real
inicio
menor <- 999
 para contador de 0 ate 9 faca
      escreva ("Idade: ")
       leia(idade)
      idade_media <- idade_media + idade
   se (idade <= menor) entao
      menor <- idade
      fimse
   se (idade>=maior) entao
      maior <- idade
      fimse
   fimpara
 idade_media <-idade_media/10
 escreval
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Posso pecar na sintaxe exata do Portugol/Visualg, mas a ideia é válida. Peço para corrigir eventual deslize meu

O `repita`, assim como o `para` é uma instrução de repetição.

Uso :

```
repita
    # códigos e mais códigos vem aqui
até <<condição de parada>>
```

É similar em conceito ao `enquanto`, no sentido de que ele não fornece estrutura para evolução da repetição, essa evolução precisa ser controlada internamente, no bloco de código.

No exemplo, a condição de parada é idade negativa. Então, tratando apenas a condição do laço, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
leia(idade)
repita
    # faz os julgamentos de idade neste trecho
    leia(idade)
até idade < 0 # condição de parada: idade lida ser negativa

# imprime o relatórios dos julgamentos de idade
```

Note que eu removi todo o resto da lógica de sua questão e foquei apenas no controle do laço, para ficar mais fácil de visualizar o uso do `repita`.

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser assim...

```
    var
      menor,idade,maior,contador:inteiro
      idade_media:real
    inicio
      menor <- 999
      contador<-1
      repita
        escreva ("Idade: ")
        leia(idade)
        idade_media <- idade_media + idade
        se (idade <= menor) entao
          menor <- idade
        fimse
        se (idade>=maior) entao
          maior <- idade
        fimse
        contador=contador+1
    ate(contador=10)
    idade_media <-idade_media/10
    escreval(idade_media)
fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Var    
   sairLoop: caracter    
   valor01, valor02: real    
Inicio    
    repita   
        escreva("Digite o primeiro valor: ")    
        leia(valor01)    
        escreva("Digite o segundo valor: ")    
        leia(valor02)    
        escreval("Resultado: ", valor01 + valor02)    
        escreval("Deseja sair?  S / N")    
        leia(sairLoop)    
    ate sairLoop <> "N"
```